# How to remove this tricky XML duplicate node using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to remove *consecutive* duplicate node from the *same parent* and which also has *exact same children*.

**Input Scenario 1:**

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeA id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeB id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeB>
</myroot>
```

My result:

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create">
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create">
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="change">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>
    <nodeA id="b">
        <section id="i"/>
        <section id="i"/>
    </nodeA>
    <nodeB id="b">
        <section id="i"/>
        <section id="i"/>
    </nodeB>
</myroot>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeA id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeB id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeB>
</myroot>
```

In the first scenario above: only the second consecutive create has the same children and the third consecutive `create` method has different children that's why we only remove the second one.

Second input scenario (more variation):

```
<myroot>
    <nodeB id="a">
        <cell id="i">              
            <item2 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item2>

            <item2 id="0" method="create"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item2>

            <item2 id="1" method="modify">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item2>        
        </cell>        

        <cell id="i">
            <item2 id="1" method="modify"> <!-- second consecutive modify, we remove this -->
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item2>

            <item2 id="1" method="modify"> <!-- third consecutive modify, BUT different chldren, we do NOT remove this -->
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                <somechild>aa</somechild>
            </item2>

            <item2 id="1" method="delete" /> 

            <item2 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item2>

            <item2 id="1" method="delete" /> <!-- second consecutive delete, we remove this -->

            <item2 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item2>

            <item2 id="1" method="delete" />  <!-- third consecutive delete, we remove this -->           
        </cell>
    </nodeB>
</myroot>
```

**Output:**

```
<myroot>
    <nodeB id="a">
        <cell id="i">              
            <item2 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item2>

             <item2 id="0" method="create"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item2>

            <item2 id="1" method="modify">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item2>        
        </cell>        

        <cell id="i">
            <item2 id="1" method="modify">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                <somechild>aa</somechild>
            </item2>

            <item2 id="1" method="delete" /> 

            <item2 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item2>           
        </cell>
    </nodeB>
</myroot>
```

**Not working on this:**

```
    <myroot>     
        <node1 id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="stop"/>                
                <item1 id="0" method="start"> <!-- this will be treated as new starting point -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>  

            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>                
        </node1>
    </myroot>

output:

    <myroot>     
        <node1 id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="stop"/>                          
            </section>                  
            <section id="i"/>                              
        </node1>
    </myroot>

The correct output should be:

    <myroot>     
        <node1 id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>                   
                <item1 id="0" method="stop"/>                
                <item1 id="0" method="start"> <!-- this will be treated as new starting point -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>                  
            <section id="i" />                   
        </node1>
    </myroot>
```

Can anyone helped me with this tricky removal using XSLT?
THanks very much.

John

Comment: John, can you use XSLT 2.0 (as implemented by Saxon or AltovaXML or XMLPrime)? It has `for-each-group` and `deep-equal`. If you want to use XSLT 1.0, how many child nodes and element names are there, are these completely arbitrary?

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes i can use XSLT 2.0 . Yes the child node is arbitrary but the method is only create, modify and delete. Only the node with delete method doesn't have children.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 sample stylesheet that should do the job or at least give you an idea how using `deep-equal` could help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*[some $el in (preceding-sibling::* , preceding::*) satisfies deep-equal(., $el)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
With the new requirement I don't see a way to solve that with `deep-equal` only so I wrote a new stylesheet that uses `for-each-group` and `deep-equal`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="first-in-group" as="element()*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="concat(node-name(.), '|', @id)">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*" group-by="concat(@id, '|', @method)">
            <xsl:sequence 
              select="for $pos in 1 to count(current-group())
                      return current-group()[$pos]
                              [every $item 
                              in subsequence(current-group(), 1, $pos - 1) 
                              satisfies not(deep-equal($item, current-group()[$pos]))] "/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="first-in-group" select="$first-in-group" tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*">
    <xsl:param name="first-in-group" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$first-in-group intersect .">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With that stylesheet Saxon 9.4, when applied against the sample

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeA id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeB id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeB>
</myroot>
```

outputs

```
<myroot>
   <nodeA id="a">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't re
move this --><somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="b">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't re
move this --><somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeB id="b">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, but children have different value , so we don't re
move this --><somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeB>
</myroot>
```

sop hopefully all is removed you want to be removed and all is kept you want to keep.

Comment: That's really2 cool! Thanks so much for your solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, after a more thorough testing, it seems that the solution did not consider that it's only happen in the current nodeA/nodeB with same id (for example nodeA id="a") because there can be another <nodeA id="b"> in one file. Would you mind updating it to reflect the condition? If you need me to add more example please let me know. Thanks very much.

Comment: John, please post more samples to illustrate your requirements, for instance the current sample you have where the stylesheet fails, the output you want in that case and the one you get.

Comment: I have updated Scenario 1. Actually I just copy it from the previous <nodeA id="a"> and it should produce exactly the same result because the id is different. Your solution is already perfect, just need to consider nodeA, nodeB, nodeX scope.

Comment: I see that it's really complicated and it works. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I have added a scenario where the solution is not working. I'm thinking of resetting `$pos` each time it found the `same element name, same id and same method`. So it will be applying the algorithm all over again just like the first time but I haven't got the idea of how to implement it in xslt. Thanks very much for the help.